# How to assign multiple values to an int?

Tags: int

For my assignment, I need to assign one int variable with numbers 1 to 31. It's going to represent the number of days in a month. Are there any ways to do this without creating a second variable?

Comment: do you mean like using an array of `int`s? - one variable can only contain one value at a time so...

Comment: you can use a array for this.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is that you use an array/list to do this. They are handy for storing multiple elements, in your case, numbers.